# HPWH better to raise temperature or use high demand mode

Tags: water-heater, plumbing-fixture, energy-efficiency

I have a hybrid heat pump water heater (compressor plus resistance heating elements).

I'm going to have company over for a week so 6 people, instead of 2. Is it better to increase the tank temperature (currently 120), use high demand mode (uses elements plus compressor for quicker recovery), or both?

Everyone may be taking showers in the same 2-4 hour period in the evening.
There is a thermostatic valve after the heater to prevent water hotter than 120 from going to the house.

Thoughts?

Comment: You need to look at the tank's rating.  Tanks should have a maximum rating.  When I tried to do this one of mine, I was told that the limit is to stop deformation of the steel etc, due to expansion.

Comment: What size HPWH?

Comment: I think if a mob of people are occupying a house, they need to rethink their showering plans to something other than cramming them all into a 2 hour window. But yes, as ecnerwal says, you should be raising temp to ~140F for safety, since you have a mixing valve to keep temperatures safe and don't have to worry about scalding.  You could raise it higher still for more capacity.

Answer (score 5):

As you have a tempering valve, the tank temperature should be raised. Indeed, the tank temperature is presently set too low to effectively kill *[legionella](https://www.cdc.gov/healthywater/drinking/preventing-waterborne-germs-at-home.html)* bacteria.

If that proves insufficient, add the resistive elements. Raising the stored water temperature will increase the effective capacity (since less hot water is required to get usable temperature shower water) and the tempering valve should prevent any issues with scalding.